# Push notification not delivered from Amazon Pinpoint Campaigns

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, aws-pinpoint

I created a Amazon Pinpoint project using a production certificate from my Apple developer account, I configured my Xcode project with the project ID and APS environment equal to 'production' , I upload the app to TestFlight and then install it in my device, when I send a message using the 'Test messaging' Amazon Pinpoint option (using an specific Endpoint Id or Device Token) the push notification is sent and received in my device, but when I launch a Campaign everything looks ok but I never received the push notification in my device, regardless that the segment I choose is dynamic and shows 1 eligible endpoint (I assume is mine because only I have installed this version).

Can anyone shed any light on this? Thanks in advance!

P.D: In the development environment both works, the message to specific device and the campaign.

UPDATE: I've research in all Amazon pinpoint documentation and is unclear the solution and in other posts from AWS forums and stackoverflow I found that the solution is use the APNs Production certificate and I've already done this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this line of code in the function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, the debug mode was always in true:

```
// Enabling app to receive push notification from Amazon Pinpoint
// Instantiate Pinpoint
   let pinpointConfiguration = AWSPinpointConfiguration
            .defaultPinpointConfiguration(launchOptions: launchOptions)
// Set debug mode to use APNS sandbox, make sure to toggle for your production app
   pinpointConfiguration.debug = false
   pinpoint = AWSPinpoint(configuration: pinpointConfiguration)
```

So the device could not be able to receive the remote notification from Amazon pinpoint